# Solving a parametric inequality for x

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality

I'm studying for test and I have problem with following parametric inequality for $x$:

$$x^2a+(3-a)x+1>0.$$

However, I fail to separate $x$ from $a$.
The last step I was able to do was:

$$x^2a+3x-xa>-1.$$

How should I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Separate between the cases $a > 0$, $a <  0$ and $a = 0$. To isolate $x$ is equivalent to find the values for which the polynomial is positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x)={x-3\over x(x-1)}$.

Let $m$ be a local minimum for $f$ (which is in $(0,1)$) and $M$ local maximum for $f$ (which is in $(3,\infty)$).

[image]

$$a(x^2-x)>-x-3$$

So for $x\in (0,1)$ we have $$a<f(x)$$ and for $x\notin (0,1)$ we have $$a>f(x)$$

- $x\in (0,1)$ then for $a<m$ the solution is each $x \in(0,1)$, for $a=m$ solution is $(0,1) \setminus \{x_m\}$ and for $a>m$ the solution is $(0,x_1)\cup (x_2,1)$ where $x_{1,2}$ are solutions to $x^2a+(3-a)x+1=0$
- Try your self for $x\notin (0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

You may separate $x$ and $a$ by factorizing the inequality as below,

$$(x-x_1)(x - x_2) > 0$$

where,

$$x_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2a}\left[a-3\pm\sqrt{(a-1)(a-9)}\right]$$